# Writing the expected value of a random variable in terms of its cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

My professor said that an alternative expression for the expected value of a random variable can be written as:

$$ E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-F_X(x)) \, dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x) \, dx $$

No proof was provided and I cannot find any such representation online.

How is this possible?

Comment: that works for nonnegative random variables

Comment: @Calculon - thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Calculon - actually, are you sure about that? I think the negative part is subtracted away.

Comment: I think you are right.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write $F_X(x) = E[I\{X \le x\}]$ and use Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Should I show the RHS equals the LHS?

Comment: The equation in my Post is simply the definition of the CDF, it should be clear that it holds. Start with the RHS in your post and show that it equals the LHS.